# facing an error while installing deep learning framework (Caffe)

Tags: python, c, cmake, caffe

I'm trying to install **Caffe** framework on Windows 10 for training a deep learning model using python and I'm facing the error below when I run the file 'build-win.cmd' :

```
    The system cannot find the drive specified.
The system cannot find the drive specified.
INFO: ============================================================
INFO: Summary:
INFO: ============================================================
INFO: MSVC_VERSION               = 14
INFO: WITH_NINJA                 = 1
INFO: CMAKE_GENERATOR            = "Ninja"
INFO: CPU_ONLY                   = 0
INFO: CUDA_ARCH_NAME             = Auto
INFO: CMAKE_CONFIG               = Release
INFO: USE_NCCL                   = 0
INFO: CMAKE_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS    = 0
INFO: PYTHON_VERSION             = 2
INFO: BUILD_PYTHON               = 1
INFO: BUILD_PYTHON_LAYER         = 1
INFO: BUILD_MATLAB               = 0
INFO: PYTHON_EXE                 = "python"
INFO: RUN_TESTS                  = 0
INFO: RUN_LINT                   = 0
INFO: RUN_INSTALL                = 0
INFO: ============================================================
The system cannot find the path specified.
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 3.7.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 3.7.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Users/Aryan/Desktop/cmake/cmake-3.20.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: D:/caffe/scripts/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/Users/Aryan/Downloads/Compressed/ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_105cf && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_105cf.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
    [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_105cf.exe
    FAILED: cmTC_105cf.exe
    cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\clang.exe   CMakeFiles/cmTC_105cf.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -o cmTC_105cf.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_105cf.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
    clang.exe: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
    clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/caffe/scripts/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/caffe/scripts/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
ERROR: Configure failed
```

I have installed **clang** for the C compiler and I've also added it to PATH.

any solution on how to overcome this error would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the Windows build, if my memory serves me right, Visual Studio 2013 or 2015 were supported. In order to have a successful compilation, you need to have one of those